# API search in javascript to return filtered list only

Tags: javascript, filter, fetch-api

I am trying to make a filtered API search and only display the data (users) that has been filtered. However my search seems to return all the data and not just the data that has been filtered out. I can see the right data in the console log but can't seem to figure out how to get it to render on display.

For example, if I search for janet, I can see all the data that contains the name janet when I console log it but on display it still displays all the users. What am I doing wrong?

```
const UserList = document.getElementById('userList');
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar'); 
let data = []; 

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchString = e.target.value;
   
    console.log(e.target.value)
    const filteredUsers = data.data.filter((user) => {
        return (
            user.first_name.includes(searchString) ||
            user.email.includes(searchString)
        );
    });
    console.log(filteredUsers)
    displayUsers(filteredUsers); 
});

const loadUsers = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users');
        data = await res.json();
        displayUsers(data);
        console.log(data)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const displayUsers = (users) => {
    const htmlString = data.data
        .map((user) => {
            return `
            <li class="user">
                <h2>${user.first_name}</h2>
                
            </li>
        `;
        })
        .join('');
    userList.innerHTML = htmlString;
};

loadUsers();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On displayUsers function you are mapping on data.data variable. You should use users.map.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the problem, but you are defining `UserList` at the top and then using `userList` at the bottom, small typo maybe?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out!